# GET Method to return HTML and POST to JSON

Tags: java, spring, api, post, get

Using Java and Spring Boot

I am new to Java and Spring,
working on a test to create a GET and POST APIs

I need to create a GET that should return HTML that contains:
Tags  ...  where I can paste a code snippet;

Then take this code snippet and pass it to POST Method.

The GET method is:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/code/new", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)

      public String getNewAsHTML() {
          return "index";
}
```

The POST method is :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/code/new", consumes = "application/json")
    public String newPostedCode(@RequestBody String code) {
        //  return new ResponseEntity(new CodeSharingPlatformController(), HttpStatus.OK);
        newCode.setCode(code);
        newCode.setDate(new Date());
        return code;
    }
```

and the HTML Page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function send() {
    let object = document.getElementById("code_snippet").value;

    let json = JSON.stringify(object);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", '/api/code/new', false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send(json);

    if (xhr.status == 200) {
 alert("Success!");
    }}
</script>
<textarea id="code_snippet"></textarea>
<button id="send_snippet" type="submit" onclick="send()">Submit</button>.
</body>
</html>
```

when I try to write something inside the textarea (e.g: "This is my text")
the returned text in "code" object is:

```
"code": "\"This is my text\""
```

(this is how it appears in Postman)

I need to only return the text written inside the textArea.

Comment: "I need to only return the text written inside the textArea." - that wouldn't be JSON then but rather a plain text response. Also note that your post method returns `code` (just the parameter without doing anything) but sets properties of `newCode` which seems to be defined elsewere. In order to reduce confusion you might either remove that code if it's irrelevant or add more/explain what that part is doing and how it is relevant. Ideally read [ask] to get a more complete picture.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, newCode is the Class object. I am updating its properties (code and date) to maintain the status.